# Clear selection for Kendo Grid in Angular 2

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I've got an application that allows a user to select a row in a Kendo Angular 2 grid and click a button that removes that row.  After the row is removed, however, the grid selection persists on the index of the row that was just removed.  I'd like to clear the grid's selection after the button is clicked and the row is removed.  For the life of me, I cannot find a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

The Kendo Grid control has a property of "selectedKeys" which binds to an array of numbers.  You can then clear this array when you want to clear the selection of the grid.

```
<kendo-grid
[selectedKeys]="mySelection"></kendo-grid>
```

In your code:

```
this.mySelection = [];
```

Comment: Dont forget to set '[kendoGridSelectBy]' to the template, without which [selectedKeys] will throw an error 'Can't bind to 'selectedKeys' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'.'

Comment: [Here there is a code sample](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/#toc-persisting-the-selection) from the official documentation